# D&B API version 2, REST Authentication using PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, authentication

I want get Authentication Token of D&B API version 2 REST methodology

http://developer.dnb.com/docs/2.0/common/authentication-process

**Sample Request - Get New Token**

POST https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication

x-dnb-user: P2000000FD4A9DE85D848229E03507C8

x-dnb-pwd: volcano

I have already tested these credentials on Chrome Extension (Advanced REST Client), they worked fine.

So now How can I achieve this using PHP code, Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('x-dnb-user: P2000000FD4A9DE85D848229E03507C8','x-dnb-pwd: volcano'));

    $param_array = array();
    $param_query_string = http_build_query($param_array);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param_query_string);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I had a discusstion with DnB technical team and they sent me .NET example code, I learned code and applied same logic using PHP and it worked finally.